# Laravel, JWT authentication is successful but check return false

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, jwt

I use this class for multiple projects and I never had any problems,

Today impossible to check user after JWT authentication

```
public function check()
{
    return response()->json( Auth::guard()->check());
}

public function login(Request $request)
{

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($token = Auth::guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => __('commons.response.error.login')], 401);
}

protected function respondWithToken(string $token)
{
    return response()->json([
        'check'        => Auth::guard()->check(),
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type'   => 'bearer',
        'auth'         => true,
        'me'           => Auth::guard()->user(),
        'message'      => __('commons.response.success.login', ['user' => Auth::guard()->user()->name]),
    ]);
}
```

The login function returns the user and `check` return true

After that, `check()` return false

any idea ?

Thank you

**Edit**

I find it, it was a front end issue, the request token cannot be found

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ` + localStorage.token;
```

I miss the line

`localStorage.setItem('token', r.data.access_token);`

Done